# Special characters xml parsing issue in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

When i try to parse xml containing email address say john@abc.com, it just shows "abc.com". 
How can i make it to show the complete email address. In other cases i've removed some special charcters by using the following:-

```
 string=[string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"$" withString:@""];
```

but here i've to include the symbol "@" and characters before it.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Try this accesstoken = [accesstoken stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

Comment: Are you sure your parser is working correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well... finally found a solution for myself. I converted the xml data into a string and replaced characters. Below is the code:-

```
NSError* error;
NSString *content = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:url encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding error:&error];
content=[content stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&#64;" withString:@"@"];
NSData *data = [content dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Problem Solved :)

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *string = @"$amdocs.com";
string=[string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"$" withString:@"@"];
NSLog(@"%@",string);
```

maybe it will help you.

Comment: I think what you are doing here is replacing the string "$" with "@". Guess my problem is not that :)